# Cannot connect to TFS after website deployment

Tags: asp.net-mvc, tfs

I have created a project in MVC that connects to TFS and brings the work items , i am displaying those work items according to my requirement. My project worked well on localhost , as soon i deployed it on some server , i am failing to connect to TFS , all it says is "Unauthorised".
Any help ?

Comment: How are you authenticating against the TFS server?

Comment: Windows Authentication

Comment: is your IIS app pool on the server running under the same user as your local app pool?

Comment: i will have to check the user for local app pool , can tht be an issue?

Comment: Permissions is your issue yes. If they are running under the same user, check that the user has access to the path on the server where the code is located (set security > permissions on the folder and add that user).

Comment: this application will be used company wide , it wont have a single or specific user , what shall i do in that case?

Comment: You'd have to provide a login mechanism on your application (if you haven't already), but the site itself in IIS will have to run under a user that has access to the appropriate code path.

Comment: The users are automatically logged in using Windows Authentication , does that count in login mechanism?

Answer (score 1):

You are running into the dreaded double hop authentication problem.

In AD you are authenticated by virtue of a Kerberos token. That token is issues to the machine that you are logged into and is only valid on that machine or one it directly connects to.

So you can use your local host token to authenticate to TFS, but as soon as you have a second hop (local->webserver->tfs) your authentication fails.

This is security by design.

To resolve this you need to use SetSPN to create a Service Principal Name (SPN) in AD that allows you to reuse the token on the web server.

You can create an SPN that only works for the webserver but you can't then deploy elsewhere. A better way is to create an SPN for the service account that you run the WebServer AppPool under. Then you can run it anywhere.